Azure DevOps Board/Backlog items reordering
Folks, I would like to ask for your assistance. First of all, I sincerely apologize for the lengthy description.
Currently, we work with Azure DevOps Boards and are trying to follow Nexus Scrum. We have multiple teams, each with its own inherited space.
For example, we have:

Root Product Backlog under Area Path "Master"
Team Sprint Backlog under Area Path "Master/Earth" or "Master/Moon"

The Master view is configured as "Bugs are managed with requirements" because we may find additional bugs after regression or ad-hoc testing and want them under the Feature level (we don't want to reopen closed User Stories).
The Child (Team) view is configured as "Bugs are managed with tasks" since we often find bugs related to current development during User Story development.
Thus, we have two levels of bug presentation:

Requirements level (User Story level) where a bug can be added to the Feature.
Task level where a bug can be added to the User Story.


Thus, we have a problem. It seems impossible to reorder some of our items in the root Backlog view ("Master"). When I try to reorder any bug that is/was assigned to a specific team (e.g., move a bug assigned to "Master/Earth" higher to sort all bugs by severity), Azure DevOps silently skips this request. There are no errors or issues, but no changes occur, and the backlog remains the same after a page refresh.
Perhaps Azure follows internal policies for specific teams and restricts any modifications made in a root Area Path.
I assume this happens due to a specific ruleset described here: link
Could you please advise whether it's possible to set our own flow in Azure DevOps and correctly work with bugs in a backlog when they are assigned to a User Story or Feature in the context of multiple teams?
As an end result, I would like to have such Product Backlog ordering and still see the same ordering in the Sprint Backlog, while retaining the ability to drag and drop all tasks, bugs, and User Stories.


So you mean, some of you bugs are child items of features and some are child items of requirements? Would you add some screenshots to help understand your current settings or expectation instead of  long descrition?

How are your bugs managed at the moment with tasks or requirements?

Thanks for the rapid response. I've added a screenshot in first message. I understand that such a view can be broken at this moment, thus I'm trying to align it with Azure flow and our internal processes

Hi @user922871, Thanks a lot for your update. As far as I understand your concerns, I think you may have a test with the bug management settings in my answer below. Hope it helps resolve your query in this post.

Hi @user922871, Have you got a chance to go through the findings in my answer below to check you bug management settings? Hope it may help resolve your concerns in this post. Thx for your sharing.

Based on your description, I can reproduce the issue with the scenarios below.

When we have set Bugs are managed with requirements (user stories in my sample below), we can drag and drop the child bug(#2211) under the feature (#1866) on the same level as other user stories; however, this will also result in failure in moving the child bugs under the user story;


On the other hand, if we set Bugs are managed with tasks, then we cannot move the bug under the feature; however, we are able to move the child bugs under the user story;



In addition, the bug management settings can be different from team to team; that is to say the same user can move the bugs under a feature or a user story according to the Backlogs of which team with this team's bug management settings.
With those being said, you can keep the current management habits and please be advised to switch to different teams to manage your bugs on different levels. You may of course consider changing the management setting every time when you what to move bugs on different levels; but please inform your team members to pay attention when the settings need to be changed, since it might cause the bugs to be invisible on team sprint task boards or be dragged onto an unexpected level.
Kindly see more information on Show bugs on backlogs and boards - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn.

Thank you for your support! Does this mean it's impossible to keep both views simultaneously and drag-and-drop them? I want to sort bugs and tasks at the user story and feature levels. I'm looking for functionality like Windows Explorer, where I can sort containers and files (bugs) within them. Are there best practices for this? It seems I can either have an ordered sprint backlog or product backlog, but not visually separate tasks and bugs.

Hi there, Thx for the response. Per your follow-up question, your understanding is basically correct. Just keep in mind that it's impossible to keep both views simultaneously and drag-and-drop for one single team.

Let's say, for example, as a member of your development team, who usually focus on the tasks and bugs under user stories, then this team can probably set Bugs are managed with tasks in team sprint taskboards. Thus, if you are one of users in the development team, you can reorder the bugs under the team's stories in this team's Backlogs view, but you cannot reorder the bugs under this team's features (You also need to pay attention not to mistakenly move a child bug of a feature to be a child bug of a user story).

While, as a member of your test team, who usually create bugs under features, then this team can probably set Bugs are managed with requirements in team Kanban boards. Thus, if you are one of users in the test team as well, you can reorder the bugs under the team's features in this team's Backlogs view, but you cannot reorder the bugs under this team's stories (You then need to pay attention not to mistakenly move a child bug of a story to become a child bug of a feature).

In conclusion, just switch to the correct team to manage bugs on different levels; or change the bug management settings for temporary reorders and reset it back after the movement.

Hi @user922871, May I know the further discussions on the bug management settings can resolve your concerns in this post?

Thank you so much for your support! Now I understand the problem a bit better, and it occurs exactly as you mentioned. In the root backlog (Area Path "Master"), I have "Bugs are managed with requirements," and in the child backlog (Area Path "Master/Earth"), I have "Bugs are managed with tasks." For example, during feature development, we can assign bugs to multiple teams to speed up development. Bugs can be distributed across multiple iterations.

Thus, when a feature contains multiple bugs assigned to different teams, I can't reorder bugs from a Product Backlog perspective (e.g. "Master" Backlog view). Is it possible to solve this somehow? Because if I simply change Area Path of those Bugs to "Master" then everything works fine. But in this case, teams won't be able to see assigned Bugs

Thanks for the insights, but I don't quite understand how your new issue is reproduced, you didn't mention to change Area Path in the original post. I don't think they are the same queries.

Bugs management settings are configured for project teams rather than with Area Paths. When a new team is created, you can create a corresponding Area Path but not always.

You don't have to change the bug Area Paths, by switch to different teams in my answer, I meant to use the drop down menu next to the team name; I didn't suggest changing the bug Area Path. Please double check the image in my answer.

So for bugs created as the child items of features under Master path, you can request Master team to reorder such bugs managed with requirements in the Backlogs view of Master team; for bugs as the child items of user stories under Master/Earth path, you can request the Earth team to reorder those bugs managed with tasks in the Backlogs view of Earth team.

If you are the member of both teams, you can easily switch to different teams' Backlog view to reorder bugs on different levels without changing the Area Path. Hope I made myself clear this time...
